# TabLayout out of Sync with ViewPager in Design Library 23

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-tablayout

My code has been working beautifully with until I upgraded to Design Library 23.

I upgraded from:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

**Here's what happens:** I open my app. I swipe to the second tab. I then *tap* the first tab, and nothing happens. Callbacks indicate that `onTabSelectedListener` believes I am reselecting the first tab, even though I have gone to the 2nd tab via swiping and am now coming back. 
**TL;DR -** the tab selection is not being updated when I swipe to a different page (even though the animation looks like it is in sync)

Here is the code which I've been using:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_main);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Grades"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Schedule"));

viewPager = (NonSwipeableViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager_main);
pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapterMain(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        //String tag = ((PagerAdapterMain) viewPager.getAdapter()).getRegisteredFragment(viewPager.getCurrentItem()).getTag();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

I am using a custom NonSwipeableViewPager in order to prevent swiping from the 2nd tab. It overrides the following callbacks:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Disable swiping on the 2nd tab ONLY
    switch(getCurrentItem()){
        case 1:
            return false;
        default:
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Disable swiping on the 2nd tab ONLY
    switch(getCurrentItem()){
        case 1:
            return false;
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I've played around with the newer `viewPager.addONPageChangeListener` and `TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener`, but with no luck.

Comment: What about com.android.support:design:23.1.0?